# PyCharm type hinting weirdness

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, pycharm

- PyCharm version 4.5.4
- Using Python 3.4.3

For some reason I'm seeing this warning in PyCharm, it seems odd.

> Expected 'collections.Iterable', got 'range[int]' instead
>
> This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions.
> Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited
> but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be
> specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.

```
for _ in range(x):
```

To me this seems like literally the most idiomatic [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) you can write.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe this is still an issue a year later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given your report, this appears to be a bug in PyCharm.  A range object *is* an iterable, and an Iterable.  In 3.4.3:

```
>>> import collections
>>> x = 3
>>> isinstance(range(x), collections.Iterable)
True
```

Try reporting the issue to PyCharm people.

Comment: It was already there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15038 seems like it requires a specific setup of mixing interpreters. Thanks.